# jasperServer importing

Tags: import, jasperserver

I am trying to import my zip file to JasperServer. It seems to work but I cannot see the files in the repository..
Here are the steps I follow. What else should  I do to be able to see the files imported ?

1. Go to the directory

   `c:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-5.6\buildomatic`
2. Run the command

   `js-import.bat <path to zip file>`
3. Here is the log I see

   *`Started to load resources
   Resource name: applicationContext.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-adhoc.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-adhoc-dataStrategy.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-adhoc-repository.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-audit.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-cascade.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-cascading-pro.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-catFactory.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-data-snapshots.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-datarator.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-el.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-events-logging.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-export-config.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-export-import.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-export-import-audit.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-export-import-multi-tenancy.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-export-import-pro.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-export-import-report-options.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-logging.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-messages-pro.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-multiTenancy.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-multiTenancy-security.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-olap-connection.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-profiling.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-report-options.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-search.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-search-pro.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-security.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-semanticLayer.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-themes.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-themes-pro.xml
   Resource name: applicationContext-virtual-data-source.xml
   Creating ActionModelService object.
   Creating action model infrastructure.
   No input parameter was specified
    -- JasperServer:  EhCacheImpl shutdown called.  This normal shutdown operation.
    -- JasperServer:  EhCacheImpl calling cleanerTimer.cancel().  This normal shutdown operation.`*

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the option name "--input-zip" to indicate to the js-import.bat script what it has to do with the zip file name.